# Change a variable in a shell script loop

Tags: bash, shell

I'm running a command that writes warnings to stdout, and I want my script to stop on those warnings, so piecing together a lot of stuff I learned here, I have the following...

```
  warnd=false;
  myLongCommand |
    while IFS= read -r line
    do
      if [[ $line == *"WARNING in ."* ]]; then
          warnd=true;
          echo "found a warning!!!!!"
          break
      fi
      echo $line
    done
    echo WARNING IS $warnd
  if [[ "$warnd" == true ]]; then
      echo "exiting due to warning"
      exit
  else
      echo "no warnings"
  fi
```

But this doesn't work as I expect.  When myLongCommand writes a warning, I see the following echo'd...

> found a warning!!!!!
>
> WARNING IS false
>
> no warnings

Why isn't the change to my `warnd` variable seen after the loop.  I've read about scoping of shell script variables, but nothing seems to indicate that the variable inside the loop has a different scope.

Comment: Change `myLongCommand | for;do;done` to `for;do;done < <(mylongcommand)`. Pipes opens a subshell, and when it finishes closes it, causing any variable set in the subshell to be lost.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are running the command in a pipe-line and modifying a variable, which *does not* get effect after the sub-shell created by the pipe-line terminates. Use a proper process-substitution technique with a while-loop,

```
while IFS= read -r line
do
  if [[ $line == *"WARNING in ."* ]]; then
      warnd=true;
      echo "found a warning!!!!!"
      break
  fi
done< <(myLongCommand)
```

Worth reading this [BashFAQ - 024 - I set variables in a loop that's in a pipeline. Why do they disappear after the loop terminates? Or, why can't I pipe data to read?](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/024)

A simple example quoting from the linked page,

```
linecount=0

printf '%s\n' foo bar |
while IFS= read -r line
do
    linecount=$((linecount + 1))
done

echo "total number of lines: $linecount"
```

So ideally the expected value for the `lineCount` would be `2` but since the variable is updated in a sub-shell created by the pipe-line, the update does not reflect once the sub-shell exits.

FYI, the above small snippet produces an output as

```
total number of lines: 0
```

Comment: Thanks.  This solution didn't work for me, but it got me on track.  (The DUP didn't help me either).  I got `syntax error near unexpected token `<'` on that done line.  The way I fixed was to wrap everything after the command in curly braces.  Thanks for getting me on track!

Comment: @user1272965: Happy to be of help. You didn't let us know your command, else we could spotted if it had  any issues. But my answer was a general way to avoid pipelines when updating variables.